# Is there a way to set a default search path in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I used to be able to set a default absolute path when I wanted to search in files (cmd + shift + f). However, after I upgraded sublime text, this feature disappeared. How can I set a default path so that every time I hit cmd + shift + f, it shows a default path to search in (as opposed to clicking `...` and `Add Folder`).